# Does any one know of an RTF report generator in Django?

Tags: python, django, report, rtf

I know about the PDF report generator, but I need to use RTF instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [PyRTF](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRTF/0.45) but it hasn't been updated in a while.

If that doesn't work and you are willing to do some hacking then I can also point you to the [GRAMPS Project](http://www.gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) that has an RTF report generator (look in gramps/docgen/RTFDoc.py).  This code is very specific to their genealogy reporting needs, but it is clean and decently documented so could make a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

`(can't comment yet so I post it as an answer)`

There's a fork of PyRTF called [pyrtf-ng](http://code.google.com/p/pyrtf-ng/), it's maintained and has Unicode support.
Documentation doesn't exist from what I've seen, but api looks nice, and you can figure out a lot from tests in `tests` dir.

Answer (score 0):

[Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/) has a very nice RTF generator. And you create the template in Word so very easy to use. (Disclaimer - I'm the CTO at Windward.) And yes the Java engine is callable from Python.